# Reshaping with ? in tensorflow or keras

Tags: keras

Suppose I have a tensor of  shape=(232,). I want to change this tensor to tensor of shape =(?,2,2,58).

How do I achieve this ?
thanks

Comment: `?` or `None` refers to batch size in tensorflow where its value is defined in runtime. What does it refer to over here?

Comment: exactly, I know.T
he output of my layer is (?,16,16,232) and i run kmeans on it and their output had been (232,) . then I want to send this output to secend layer that need input like before forexample (?,1,1,232) . how can do it?